# Open in Product Topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathbb{R}^2|b\leq a\}$

How would we show that $A$ is open in product topologies such as $\mathbb{R}_R\times\mathbb{R}_R$, $\mathbb{R}_U\times\mathbb{R}_U$, $\mathbb{R}_R\times\mathbb{R}_L$, or $\mathbb{R}_L\times\mathbb{R}_R$?

For reference $U,R$, and $L$ are the usual, right, and left topologies, respectively.

Comment: Who told you $A$ is open?

Comment: No one. It could be that $A$ is not open in any of these. I am just curious to see how we would show $A$ is open in such topologies.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to actually figure out what each of those topologies *are*. The easiest way to do this is via bases:

- First, find a basis for each of the three "starting spaces," namely $\mathbb{R}_L$, $\mathbb{R}_R$, and $\mathbb{R}_U$.
- Next, use the following fact (which you should prove as an exercise using the definition of the product topology): if I have bases $B_1,B_2$ for topological spaces $(X_1,\tau_1), (X_2,\tau_2)$ respectively, then $$\{U_1\times U_2: U_1\in B_1,U_2\in B_2\}$$ (= the set of "basic open rectangles") is a basis for $X_1\times X_2$ with the product topology coming from $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ (note that this is **not** the same as the Cartesian product of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ as sets).

Once we've found bases $B_{R,R}, B_{R,L}, B_{L,R}, B_{U,U}$ for $\mathbb{R}_R\times\mathbb{R}_R$, $\mathbb{R}_R\times \mathbb{R}_L$, $\mathbb{R}_L\times\mathbb{R}_R$, and $\mathbb{R}_U\times\mathbb{R}_U$ respectively, we can use these to determine whether the set $A$ is open in each space in turn:

> To tell whether $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_I\times\mathbb{R}_J$ (for $I,J\in \{R,L,U\}$), you need to figure out whether for each point $\langle u,v\rangle\in A$ there is some $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\langle u,v\rangle\in W$ and $W$ is an element of the appropriate basis $B_{I,J}$.

It's a good idea to start trying to prove that it *is* open (in whichever topology you're looking at at the moment), and if that doesn't work use your failure to do so to help find a proof that it's not in fact open (again, in whichever topology).

Comment: A typical basis set for $\mathbb{R}_U \times \mathbb{R}_u$ might be in the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$. So then for $\langle u,v\rangle \in A$ $\langle u,v\rangle \in (u-1, u+1) \times (v-1, v+1)$ and $(u-1, u+1) \times (v-1, v+1)$ is an element of the basis. Does that work? Am I leaping somewhere?